# How to set Hermitian and positive semidefinite constraints in CVXPY?

Tags: python, matrix, cvxpy

I am new to `CVXPY` due to my recent project. I need to use maximum likelihood method in `python`. The matrix I want to tune is both **hermitian** and **semidefinite** (a density matrix in physics language). But I find that these two constrains cannot appear at the same time in `CVXPY`.

1. I know there is a function `hermitian_semidefinite` in `CVX` package of `matlab`, but I did not find in `python`.
2. I know there exist keyword `hermitian` and `SPD` when I initial a variable in `CVXPY`, but I can only set one keyword.

Please help me, I will appreciate any effort you offer, thanks very much.

Comment: https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html

Comment: sorry for late, I searched the document, but did not find the method to apply both these two conditions....

Comment: This is a late reply, but would it be possible to set the `cvxpy` variable to be `hermitian=True`, and then, in the constraints, enforce that `X >> 0` to obtain the additional criterion you are after?